# my fabric mod for minecraft is giving errors and warnings

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, minecraft-fabric

I have been working on this mod using vscode for a week and not much progress because i was looking at a walkthrough on YouTube, but after I have made sure I did everything that they did. I tested it and it worked a couple of days ago, however I had to restart my computer because of windows update. And when I tried to run it again it failed to start and it gave some warnings and a couple of errors.

```
[main/WARN] (mixin) @Mixin target net/minecraft/server/world/ServerWorld$ServerEntityHandler is public in fabric-lifecycle-events-v1.mixins.json:ServerWorldEntityLoaderMixin and should be specified in value
[main/WARN] (mixin) @Mixin target net/minecraft/client/world/ClientWorld$ClientEntityHandler is public in fabric-lifecycle-events-v1.mixins.json:client.ClientWorldEntityLoaderMixin and should be specified in value
[main/WARN] (mixin) @Mixin target net/minecraft/client/render/block/BlockModelRenderer$AmbientOcclusionCalculator is public in fabric-renderer-indigo.mixins.json:MixinAmbientOcclusionCalculator and should be specified in value
[main/WARN] (mixin) @Mixin target net/minecraft/client/render/chunk/ChunkBuilder$BuiltChunk$RebuildTask is public in fabric-renderer-indigo.mixins.json:MixinChunkRebuildTask and should be specified in value
[main/WARN] (mixin) @Mixin target net/minecraft/server/network/ServerPlayNetworkHandler$1 is public in fabric-events-interaction-v0.mixins.json:MixinServerPlayNetworkHandler and should be specified in value
[main/WARN] (mixin) @Mixin target net/minecraft/village/TradeOffers$TypeAwareBuyForOneEmeraldFactory is public in fabric-object-builder-v1.mixins.json:TypeAwareTradeMixin and should be specified in value
[main/WARN] (mixin) @Mixin target net/minecraft/client/font/FontManager$1 is public in fabric-resource-loader-v0.mixins.json:client.FontManagerResourceReloadListenerMixin and should be specified in value
[main/WARN] (mixin) @Mixin target net/minecraft/server/command/GameRuleCommand$1 is public in fabric-game-rule-api-v1.mixins.json:GameRuleCommandVisitorMixin and should be specified in value
[main/WARN] (mixin) @Mixin target net/minecraft/client/gui/screen/world/EditGameRulesScreen$RuleListWidget$1 is public in fabric-game-rule-api-v1.mixins.json:client.RuleListWidgetVisitorMixin and should be specified in value
[main/WARN] (mixin) @Mixin target net/minecraft/server/world/ThreadedAnvilChunkStorage$EntityTracker is public in fabric-networking-api-v1.mixins.json:accessor.EntityTrackerAccessor and should be specified in value
[main/WARN] (mixin) @Mixin target net/minecraft/client/particle/ParticleManager$SimpleSpriteProvider is public in fabric-particles-v1.mixins.json:ParticleManagerAccessor$SimpleSpriteProviderAccessor and should be specified in value
[main/WARN] (mixin) @Mixin target net/minecraft/data/server/AbstractTagProvider$ObjectBuilder is public in fabric-tag-extensions-v0.mixins.json:MixinObjectBuilder and should be specified in value
[main/WARN] (mixin) @Mixin target net/minecraft/tag/RequiredTagList$TagWrapper is public in fabric-tag-extensions-v0.mixins.json:MixinTagImpl and should be specified in value
[main/WARN] (FileUtil) Configuration conflict: there is more than one oshi.properties file on the classpath
[main/WARN] (FileUtil) Configuration conflict: there is more than one oshi.architecture.properties file on the classpath
[Render thread/INFO] (Minecraft) Environment: authHost='https://authserver.mojang.com', accountsHost='https://api.mojang.com', sessionHost='https://sessionserver.mojang.com', servicesHost='https://api.minecraftservices.com', name='PROD'
[Render thread/ERROR] (Minecraft) Failed to verify authentication
```

Comment: `there is more than one oshi.properties file on the classpath`, how about **cleaning java language server worksapce** from command palette in VS Code, and `(Minecraft) Failed to verify authentication`, This error is mostly caused when the Minecraft servers are glitched or your connection isn’t stable. you may google the error and try the posted solutions to see if it solves your question.

Comment: `(Minecraft) Failed to verify authentication` always happens with Fabric, and for "you may google the error" - this is the page I find when I Google the error